# How to create an array of initialized pointers

Tags: c

I have a structure:

```c
struct Path{
    int8_t maxtopy;
};
```

And I want to create an array of pointers to structure `Path`. I've tried something like that:

```c
int main(){
    struct Path *paths[NUMBER_OF_PATHS]; 
    init_paths(paths);
}
```

```c
void init_paths(struct Path **paths){
    paths[0]->maxtopy = -1;

    for(int i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_PATHS; i++)
        paths[i]->maxtopy = -1;
}
```

It is not going to work. Value to the first path is assigned correctly. But when `for` loop starts I am gettting **Segmentation fault**. I already figured out that when I am creating array of pointers, only the first pointer is going to be assigned to some structure. So I cannot e.g. `paths[1]->maxtopy = -1;`, because `paths[1]` doesn't point to any existing structure.

I have tried something like this:

```c
for(int i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_PATHS; i++){
        static struct Path a;
        paths[i] = &a;
        paths[i]->maxtopy = i;
}
```

It doesn't work because it initialize `a` only once. So every pointer in `paths` array points to the same structure.

My question is: **How to create an array of pointers that point to initialized structures?**

Comment: I would focus on C or C++. You're currently mixing them. Which language are you trying to write?

Comment: What does your books or tutorials tell you about *dynamic allocation*?

Comment: Why are you linking all the entries in this (unallocated) array to a singular static record?

Comment: Yes I am writting in C. I thought that C++ may have similar solution, so I added also c++ tag.

Comment: C++: `std::vector<Path>`. C: `calloc()`.

Comment: C++ is a *completely* different language. Please do not tag just for inspiration or whatever. While you can usually use C code in C++, the reverse is not true.

Comment: The big gist is you're attempting to de-reference pointers that point to nothing.

Comment: In your last example, remove the definition of `a`. Then, do `paths[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Path)); paths[i]->maxtopy = i;`

Comment: `int main() { struct Path paths_array[NUMBER_OF_PATHS]; struct Path *paths[NUMBER_OF_PATHS]; for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PATHS; ++i) paths[i] = &paths_array[i]; init_paths(paths); }`

Comment: Also, indexing should start with 0 and _not_ 1

Comment: Thank you @CraigEstey , `paths[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Path)); paths[i]->maxtopy = i;` And I know that indexing should start from 0, but as I said assigning value to the first pointer worked.

Comment: Your first pointer is *also* uninitialized. Therefore any dereference of it will lead to *undefined behavior*. Just don't do that, initialize all the nodes inside the loop properly. Of at shown by @Eljay use an array of `Path` structure objects rather than pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okey I've done it like you said. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created an array of pointers, butt the pointers need to point *to* something. You can dynamically allocate each with `malloc`.

```
struct Path{
    int8_t maxtopy;
};

int main(void) {
    struct Path *paths[NUMBER_OF_PATHS]; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PATHS; i++) {
        paths[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Path));
        paths[i]->maxtopy = i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, if your array is declared in `main` and is not of excessive size, you may want to simply write the following.

```
int main(void) {
    struct Path paths[NUMBER_OF_PATHS]; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PATHS; i++) {
        paths[i].maxtopy = i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const int NUMBER_OF_PATHS = 10;

struct Path {
    int8_t maxtopy;
};

void init_paths(struct Path** paths) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PATHS; i++) {
        paths[i] = (Path*)malloc(sizeof(Path));
        paths[i]->maxtopy = i;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct Path* paths[NUMBER_OF_PATHS];

    init_paths(paths);

    for (auto i : paths) {
        printf("%d\n", i->maxtopy);
    }
}
```

Comment: The range-based for is a C++ feature.

Comment: The range-based loop is in the same scope that declared the array. It will work. I wouldn't recommend it, but this specific scenario does work. What I like less is the attempt at providing a "C++" answer after OP has explicitly said they're working with C. Unless C got fancy while I wasn't looking.

Comment: @sweenish At the begging I added also c++ tag because I thought that C and C++ may have a similar solutions. Then I fixed that so it's my mistake

Comment: Also, in C, we don't cast the return value of `malloc` That's C++ cruft for C

Comment: @Wo1Tez tadman fixed it when they removed the c++ tag after I asked you clarify the language. You don't show up in the edit history outside of posting the original question. His edit to remove the tag just beat out mine.